# is the set of 2 by 2 upper triangular matrices an submanifold?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I have recently been practicing the regular value theorem and I have asked to determine whether the set of upper triangular matrices is a submanifold for a 2 by 2 matrix represented below.
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b\\
    c & d\\               
 \end{pmatrix}                  iff  (a,b,c,d)
$$
my initial thoughts were to try and show that 0 is a regular value and since c=0 and calulating its  derivative which is $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 &0 &0\\
    0&1&0&0\\               
    0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&1\
\end{pmatrix}                  
$$
but this isn't surjective since we have a 0 row meaning it cannot be a submanifold. is this completely wrong

Comment: Which function are you using to apply the regular value theorem?

Comment: a function that takes a set of 2 by 2 matrices to (a,b,0,d). then i calculated the jacobian from this collumn vector.

Comment: Can you think about how a linear subspace of a vector space is a submanifold, in addition to @Arctic Char's comment?

Comment: So is the space of upper triangular matrix a level set of your function?

Comment: I was thinking f^-1(0) where f: mat(2, R)→upper triangular matrix

Comment: What is $0$ in "upper triangular matrix"?

Comment: wouldn't that just be the 0 matrix

Comment: Then $f^{-1}(0) = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ c & 0 \end{pmatrix} : c\in \mathbb R\}$ is not the space of upper triangular matrix

Comment: could you please explain why  f^-1(0) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ c & 0 \end{pmatrix}

Comment: Do you know what is $f^{-1}(0)$?

Comment: i thought it would be \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}

Comment: No you said $ 0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$...

Comment: What happens if you send $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ to $c$?

Comment: The values of a,b,d are 0

Comment: Consider the mapping $f$ which sends $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ to $c$. What is $f^{-1}(0)$?

Comment: ah i see now 0 cannot be a regular value since you get \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ c & 0\end{bmatrix}